# C/C++ [ Websockets ] non resolving calling to accept method from <sys/socket.h>

Tags: c++, websocket

Hi I've created a class Websocket which manage the socket flow.
It is designed to make the following working with sockets:

- openSocket()
- bindSocket()
- listen() accept() method calling problem is here!

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

class Websocket
{
private:
    static const int domain = AF_INET;
    static const int type = SOCK_STREAM;
    static const auto internetAddressIntegers = INADDR_ANY;

    void openSocket();
    void bindSocket();
    int socketFileDescriptor;

public:
    Websocket(int port);
    bool connect();
    bool disconnect();
    void listen();

    int port;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
};
```

```
#include "Websocket.h"

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

Websocket::Websocket(int port)
{
    this->port = port;
    this->address.sin_family = this->domain;
    this->address.sin_addr.s_addr = this->internetAddressIntegers;
    this->address.sin_port = htons(this->port);
}

bool Websocket::connect()
{
    this->openSocket();
    this->bindSocket();
    return true;
}

bool Websocket::disconnect()
{
    return close(this->socketFileDescriptor);
}

void Websocket::openSocket()
{
    this->socketFileDescriptor = socket(this->domain, this->type, 0);

    if (this->socketFileDescriptor < 0)
        perror("ERROR on opening");

    printf("Socket opened \n");
}

void Websocket::bindSocket()
{
    bzero((char *) &this->address, sizeof(this->address));

    if (bind(this->socketFileDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &this->address, sizeof(this->address)) < 0)
        perror("ERROR on binding");

    printf("Socket have been bound successfully \n");
    ::listen(this->socketFileDescriptor, 5);
}

void Websocket::listen()
{
    printf("Listen method \n");
    socklen_t socketLen = sizeof(this->address);
     // The program does not advance after this line
    int newSocketFileDescriptor = accept(this->socketFileDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &this->address, &socketLen);

    if (newSocketFileDescriptor < 0)
        perror("ERROR on listening");

    printf("Socket listening on port %i \n", this->port);

    while(true)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        bzero(buffer, 256);
        int socketMessage = read(newSocketFileDescriptor, buffer, 255);

        if (socketMessage < 0)
            perror("ERROR reading from socket");

        printf("Message receive: %s \n", buffer);
    }
}
```

```
#include "socket/Websocket.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 9117

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Program started \n");

    Websocket websocket(PORT);
    websocket.connect();
    websocket.listen();

    printf("Finish program... \n");

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why on the listen method the accepting call is doesn't work. The program flow stop when accept method is invoked.
I followed this docs https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/accept.html

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Comment: Sorry, maybe is better to say: It doesn't work.
The program doesn't continue executing when accept method its invoked.

Comment: Ok, and what can you show that documents a connection attempt to the port that the socket is waiting on? `accept()` doesn't return until a connection is accepted, so why do you expect it to return?

Comment: `the accepting call is not working` What does it mean "not working"? What happens? What does not happen? What did you expect to happen? What is the program output? What did you expect the program to output? `The program doesn't continue executing` what platform (windows/linux) are you using? Does it receive a signal,if so, which one? Did you debug your program?

Comment: You know that `accept` is a blocking call (unless the socket itself is non-blocking), right?  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `The program flow stop when accept` Would you expect anything else? Do you make any connections to the program so that you expect the program not to "stop"?

Comment: Sorry I have to check again the docs.

Answer (score 0):

After in the `Websocket` constructor you correctly set `address`, you ruin this in `bindSocket` by the call

```
    bzero((char *) &this->address, sizeof(this->address));
```

- drop that, and your program will listen on the correct port.